# How to update existing stack via CLI that was original created with CodePipeline

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy

I used a basic AWS-CDK lambda app stack template. It created all the template source code and a CodeDeploy pipeline. CDK typescript names the stack `CdkStack`:

`export class CdkStack extends Stack`

However, CodePipeline deploys this stack into a stack that's named the same as my app (sample-cdk-app).

[image]

When I try to deploy the same stack from my local command line via `cdk deploy`, it tries to deploy it to stack `CdkStack` and, as opposed to updating the existing app, creates a new stack.

Is there a way to tell `cdk` to deploy to stack name that's different than what's in the typescript? How does CodePipeline do that? I compared YML templates and they are identical.

/bin folder contains the following:

````
const { ACCOUNT_ID, PARTITION, REGION, STACK_NAME } = Aws;
const permissionBoundaryArn = `arn:${PARTITION}:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:policy/${STACK_NAME}-${REGION}-PermissionsBoundary`;

// Apply permissions boundary to the stack
stack.node.applyAspect(new PermissionsBoundaryAspect(permissionBoundaryArn));```
````

Comment: Can you show the definition of your stack in your /bin file? The name of the stack class should not impact your outcome, but the names of the stack instances within your bin file determine what will be deployed and what stack names can be passed when invoking deploy.

Comment: @jonlegend updated the question with contents of /bin. So is CodePipeline modifying that file to change the name of the stack it's deploying to?

Comment: Somewhere in the process of deploying a stack is being instantiated. Typically this is done in your \bin file, something like 
new cdkStack(*someapp*,"stackName", {other args})
I am not certain where you are doing that in your code, but search for the instantiation of the stack, the stack id is the second argument, and that is what is used by default when you "cdk deploy" you can change that id to match your pipeline deployed stack to have cdk deploy update the same stack. 
Pipeline is likely instantiating the stack, and providing the stack id somewhere in its configuration.